# Restore function in unix

Tags: shell-script, files, directory, data-recovery

I have a script to recover files back to their original location. I am missing the options for the script to as "Do you want to recover this file?" Yes or No. How will I implement it into this code below
Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
echo -e "Usage:\n\n\t$0 'file name'"
exit 1
fi

f=$(ls 2>/dev/null -l /proc/*/fd/* | fgrep "$1 (deleted" | awk '{print $9}')

if [[ $f ]]; then
   echo "fd $f file found..."
cp -v "$f" "$1"
   else
echo >&2 "No file"
exit 2
fi
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `read` to ask for confirmation, e.g. like this:

```
echo "fd $f file found..."
read -p "Press enter to continue or Ctrl+c to cancel"
cp -v "$f" "$1"
```

or

```
echo "fd $f file found..."
read -p "Do you want to recover this file? [Yes/No] " confirmation
[[ $confirmation =~ ^[YyJj] ]] || { echo "Canceled"; exit }
cp -v "$f" "$1"
```